# How to Install or Upgrade to Kernel 4.19 in CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, kernel, system-installation

```
# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
Release:    6.10
Codename:   Final
```

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.web-ster.com
 * elrepo: repos.lax-noc.com
 * epel: mirror.pnl.gov
 * extras: mirror.web-ster.com
 * updates: mirror.web-ster.com
repo id            repo name                                                status
WANdisco-git       WANdisco Distribution of git                                407
WANdisco-svn19     WANdisco SVN Repo 1.9 - x86_64                              162
base               CentOS-6 - Base                                           6,713
elrepo             ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Repository - el6      263
epel               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64           12,504
extras             CentOS-6 - Extras                                            35
updates            CentOS-6 - Updates                                          257
repolist: 20,341
```

```
# yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.web-ster.com
 * elrepo: repos.lax-noc.com
 * elrepo-kernel: repos.lax-noc.com
 * epel: mirror.pnl.gov
 * extras: mirror.web-ster.com
 * updates: mirror.web-ster.com
No package kernel-ml available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: `kernel-ml` is only for CentOS7 -  See http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml . You can see the list in elrepo for CentOS 6 at https://elrepo.org/linux/kernel/el6/x86_64/RPMS/

Comment: It appears that only LTS kernels (`kernel-lt`) are available for `el6`.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the repo manually at http://repos.lax-noc.com/elrepo/kernel/el6/x86_64/RPMS/ and there is no package named `kernel-ml`. Perhaps this is a typo and you want to install `kernel-lt` package

Comment: kernel-ml was available up until 1 month ago. The issue is I'd like to be able to install the latest greatest stable kernel from mainline.

Comment: Looks like it is not anymore, elrepo lists only for centos 7 http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml

Comment: So how do  I install latest mainline kernel on centos 6 ?